# is it possible to change pine script strategy's messagebox value?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

whenever i create strategy alert i need to input '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}'

but is it possible insert this value to messagebox automatically whenever i create alert ?

i searched bunch of time but i couldn't found any clue related this problem.

for instance i was insert this value 'alertcondition(close>open, message=" {{strategy.order.alert_message}} ")' in code but no luck.

if anyone help me much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert any custom message by placing the following comment with a `@strategy_alert_message`.

```
// @strategy_alert_message {{strategy.order.alert_message}}
```

The message will automatically replace the default message text in the strategy alert dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot alter that. As an alternative, you can generate the message programmatically and use the `alert()` function. In that case, you wouldn't worry about the alert message because it would be generated automatically and the message box would look like below:

[image]

Comment: reason why i want to add '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' this message is i creating many of bot so want to add this message into messagebox. thanks anyway